# append url with a session id jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a static session ID i'm using and need to add it to a url when clicked, but can't seem to get it right. If you go to http://www.mysite.com/test.php you get redirected, the session id XYX needs to be added, so the correct url to hit the page would be http://www.mysite.com/test.php?sessionid=XYX

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.php" class="foo">link here</a>

$('.foo').click(function(){
  (this).append(?sessionid=XYX');'
});
```

I know this is wrong, all documentation Ive found is much more complex than my needs. thanks!

Comment: I already posted an answer, but now I'm not sure I answered the right question.  Do you want to update all the links with class `foo` to have the session id when the page loads, or not until the link is clicked?

Comment: I need to append the url when the link is clicked. thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should add the session ID and send the user to the new url, use the [`e.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the system using the normal event, then add the session id to the url and send the browser there:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.php" class="foo">link here</a>

$('.foo').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?sessionid=XYX';
});
```

Comment: thx man, I totally forgot about the e.preventDefault(); Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem at all, sometimes its the little bits that are the hardest to spot and cause the headaches because they are so easy to miss!

Comment: @Dirty: You wanted to change the `window.location`?

Comment: @patrick dw - yes i wanted to change it from <a href='http://www.mysite.com/test.php'> link </a> to <a href='http://www.mysite.com/test.php?sessionid=XYX'>link</a> when the user clicks the link

Comment: @Dirty: Alright, I'm confused. But as long as you've got it figured out, I'm happy. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change the href attribute, like this:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?sessionid=XYX');
});
```

I was actually skeptical of this for a moment - I wasn't sure if the change to the URL was going to affect the destination of the link, but it does.  The change happens and then after it's done, the default action fires, loading the modified link.  Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mgv34/

Comment: this works too, If I could accept 2 answers I would. I really appreciate the help thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
  if( !this.search ) this.search = '?sessionid=XYX';
});
```

The `search` property lets you set the query string directly on the element.

Comment: Got any documentation on the search property?  I've not heard of it before and it sounds interesting.

Comment: @Surreal: Not off hand, but I'm looking around. The parts of the `href` of an `<a>` can be accessed via properties like `search,hash,hostname,pathname`.

Comment: @Surreal: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement The properties of the Anchor element are listed. The `search` property is listed as HTML5, but I'll have to double check. I was pretty sure it is widely adopted, and may just now be included in the standard, like `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Surreal: You're welcome. Just to follow up, I tested this in IE6 and Firefox (latest) and it works. Without doing further testing, I'd say it's a pretty safe bet. :o)

Comment: Wow, IE6 support too?  Wish I'd known about this ages ago.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing hrefs with onClick is dangerous without checking if the href contains '?sessionid=XYX', because next clicks to the link gives you "http://www.example.com/test.php?sessionid=XYX?sessionid=XYX"

I suggest

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
  var lHref = $(this).attr('href');
  var lStr = '?sessionid=XYX';
  if (lHref.indexOf(lStr) < 0) { 
    $(this).attr('href', lHref + lStr);
  }
});
```